# Why does setting a Winforms DateTimePicker to DateTime.MinValue fail?

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

I have the following code in my Winforms OnLoad event:

```
dtpStartDateFilter.Value = DateTime.MinValue;
```

`dtpStartDateFilter` is a standard WinForms date time picker.  When my form loads it encounters the previously entered code line and then exits (with WinForms eating the exception so I have no idea what it is).

What's wrong with doing this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

DateTimePicker.MinimumDateTime > DateTime.MinValue

[DateTime.MnValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.minvalue.aspx)

> The value of this constant is equivalent to 00:00:00.0000000, January
>   1, 0001.

[DateTimePicker.MinimumDateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.mindate%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

> The minimum date and time that can be selected in the control. The
>   default is 1/1/1753 00:00:00.

Comment: Yep that was the issue.  Thanks!

Comment: Note that there is a typo, a missing 'i' in `DateTime.MinValue` but it can't be fixed alone because of the 6 character minimum.