# c# DateTimePicker validation sets on unselected or unpicked values

Tags: c#, datetimepicker

How to declare the datetimepicker value as null? This is my code.

```
dateTimePicker.Value.ToString() == string.Empty
```

could you please edit my code. because it is unrunnable.

Comment: `DateTimePicker.Value` is not a nullable type, you can't assign `null` to it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to set datetimepicker with null value if date not selected(c# winforms)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983563/how-to-set-datetimepicker-with-null-value-if-date-not-selectedc-winforms)

Comment: are the title and the post relevant?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set `null` value there. `DateTimePicker.Value` is not nullable and its minimum value is `1/1/1753 00:00:00`

If you are going to assign null just to check if it is initialized. You can check the value against [MinDate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.mindate(v=vs.71).aspx) property.

Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7465933/why-does-setting-a-winforms-datetimepicker-to-datetime-minvalue-fail).

Answer (score 0):

Because the datatype of `DateTimePicker.Value` property is `DateTime`, just checking whether the year is greater than `1900` would give only valid dates. You can change the year value to something more recent if your application demands so, but anything after `1900` is generally considered a valid date.

```
dateTimePicker.Value.Year > 1900
```

Answer (score 0):

/*
Here is a Method I wrote to validate expiry id ID in C# when selecting Date in DateTime Picker for Windows Forms. By demonguru18 aka techhowdy.com
*/

```
private bool isIDExpired()
        {
            DateTime objDateTime = DateTime.Parse(dtpIDExpiry.Value.ToString());
            DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
            int day = objDateTime.Day - today.Day;
            int month = objDateTime.Month - today.Month;
            int year = objDateTime.Year - today.Year;
            if (day == 0 && month == 0 && year == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Your ID is Expiring Today. Please Provide new ID Expiry Date.");
                return false;
            }
            else if (year < 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Your ID has already Expired. Please Provide valid ID Expiry Date.");
                return false;
            }
            else if (month < 0 &&  year < 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Your ID has already Expired. Please Provide valid ID Expiry Date.");
                return false;
            }

            else if (month == 0 && day < 0 && year == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Your ID has already Expired. Please Provide valid ID Expiry Date.");
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }`
```